# React component - Errors on React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, use-effect, react-component

I'm getting 2 errors while loading my component's code:

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

and also

**Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state**

After some research I found out that probably wrapping my return statement with UseEffect might solve this issue. However, I could not manage to make the wrap properly. Any clues on how I can manage to do that?

Here is my code, which is giving rise to the errors:

```
export function CardTransition({ cards, CardsContainer }) {  
    const [cardss, setCards] = useState(cards);
    const [ expandedCardId, setExpandedCardId ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => { setCards(cards) }, [cards]);

    function handleExpandClick(expanded, id) {
        setExpandedCardId(expanded ? id : undefined);
    }

    function GetExpandedContent() {
        let item;
        for(let i=0; i<cardss.length; i++)
        {
            item = cardss[i].find(item => item && item.type.displayName === expandedCardId);
            if (item) break;
        }
        return item ? React.cloneElement(item, { onExpandClick: handleExpandClick, isExpanded: true }, undefined) : <span/>;
    }

    return <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
        <CSSTransition key={expandedCardId ? expandedCardId : ""} classNames="transitionCardsExpand" timeout={{ enter: 300, exit: 300 }} >
            {(!expandedCardId) ?
                CardsContainer(handleExpandClick)
                : GetExpandedContent()
            }
        </CSSTransition>
    </SwitchTransition> 
}

export default CardTransition;
```

I am calling the component in another class, this way:

```
return <CardTransition cards={cards} CardsContainer={cardsContainer} />;
```

Ps: CardsContainer is a function that receives a parameter in CardTransition's scope:

```
function cardsContainer(handleExpandClick) { 
        return(
        <div className={"container-fluid pl-0 pr-0"}>
            <div className="row ml-0 mr-n3">
                <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-2 mb-3 pl-0">
                    <div>
                        <OtherComponent id={id} rowVersion={rowVersion} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                {cards.map((group, x) =>
                    <div key={x} className="col-md-12 col-lg-5 pl-0">
                        {group.map((item, y) => {
                            if (!item) return null;
                            return (<div key={y} className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                    <Card>{React.cloneElement(item, { onExpandClick: handleExpandClick }, undefined)}</Card>
                                </div>
                            </div>);
                        })}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>)
    }
```

Comment: If you comment out `setExpandedCardId` from `handleExpandClick` will you still be getting the error?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova By commenting this line out my card no longer expands. I need this because of the call CardsContainer(handleExpandClick), inside the return statement

Comment: I understand that, I don't propose it as a solution, but rather a way of troubleshooting

Comment: Without this code, I do not get the error, @NadiaChibrikova

Comment: Can you add CardsContainer code? There is something wrong with the way it consumes the handler

Comment: sure, @NadiaChibrikova. I added it to my question. Thanks for helping

Comment: Ah, it's just passing it down. What is actually consuming it? Where is onExpandClick triggered?

Comment: This line `useEffect(() => { setCards(cards) }, [cards]);` doesn't make any sense. Also, why are you cloning the item?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova it is triggered when the user presses a btn to expand the Card. Then an id is passed

Comment: @JaredSmith ok, I removed it. It was just an attempt to fix it, but the errors were not related with cards... I do not know much about React yet

Comment: Change `setExpandedCardId` to `console.log` and I bet you'll see it is triggered on render, which it should not.

Comment: @PedroCoelho not a problem

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova How can I check if it is triggered on render?

Comment: Add a breakpoint or console.log(id)

Comment: the console.log(id) only print the card's id. How can I know if render triggered it?

Comment: If you didn't expand it and it got logged, it was triggered for no reason, right?

Comment: right, but even if it did not expand, I triggered the event by clicking the expansion icon

Comment: So what's inside the Card component?